# Catch not working, why?

Tags: java, android, exception

When the following code runs, an exception occurs at the setImageResource line.
When I debug it, the right after that line the debugger jumps to the finally part, and then it goes into some java code in Runtimeinit.java to a method called
private static class UncaughtHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
If I remark the finally section, then the exception is not caught by the catch part?

Why isn't the catch part working? Isn't "catch (Exception ex)" supposed to catch any type of exception?

```
try {
    ImageView imageV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Log.i(TAG, "before setImageResource");
    imageV.setImageResource(R.drawable.merle);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(TAG,ex.getMessage().toString());
} finally {
    Log.i(TAG,"finally");
}
```

Comment: `Isn't "catch (Exception ex)" supposed to catch any type of exception?` Not **any type**. Only the recognized ones.

Comment: It catch Exception but not Throwable, maybe the exception thrown inherit from Throwable rather than Execption.

Comment: Can you Show the full stacktrace?

Comment: I think, the exception which you are getting is not subclass of Exception, that's why it s not going to catch block. Please post full stracktrace if you can.

Comment: If you want to catch all exceptions and errors, catch Throwable instead of Exception

Comment: Be careful catching Throwable because that includes Error and these are not really supposed to be caught they probably should stop the JVM to prevent causing serious trouble with.